# How to programmatically create an X.509 certificate in .NET?

Tags: .net, cryptography, x509

I'd like to create a new X.509 certificate in .NET, that meet the hash algorithm and key length requirements that I set.  This will be a self-signed certificate.  Creating a new certificate may create a new key, or perhaps I'd like to import an existing private key that I have in byte[] form.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37563051/3063273 for a solution that uses Bouncy Castle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original blog post has vanished.

Luckily [there are better ways to achieve the same goal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide) now

**Original answer**

Maybe [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dcook/archive/2008/11/25/creating-a-self-signed-certificate-in-c.aspx) can be helpful. I use this code in our test environment to create self signed certificates.

Best

Comment: 403 Forbidden.  -1