# Uploading a x509 cert to Application Manifest on Azure ADD or Microsoft Registration Portal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Sorry for the multiple post about the same issue!

I'm trying to upload a self signed sertificate to application manifest created on Microsoft Registration Portal but I have some issues which I don't completly understand why, According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153189/upload-x509-certificate-to-azure-application-manifest-programmatically), it's very much possible to upload the certificate using **DELEGATED PERMISSIONS** however I don't see the reason why I can't use **Application Permissions** since I only need the AccessToken and I get that with the client_credential grant flow,

Below is the code that I have tried but when retrieving the token with client_credential grant flow, I get stuck att `var application = activeDirectoryClient.Applications["ApplicationObjectId"].ExecuteAsync().Result;`

and when trying to use the code given to my by Tom Sung in the previous post, the applications exits with error "must have client_credentil or client_assertion in request body"

this is the code that I have tried:

```
 private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync(string graphResourceId, string tenantId, string clientId, string userId)
    {

        string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/token";
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContextt =
            new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token");
        AuthenticationResult result =
            await authenticationContextt.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId,
                clientCredential);
        //token is acquiered and gets stuck 
        var e = result.AccessToken;


        //Tom Suns code
        IPlatformParameters parameters = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.SelectAccount);
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientId, new Uri("http://localhost"), parameters, new UserIdentifier(userId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
        //exits with error
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }


try
 {          
    var graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
    var userId = "****";
    //used to test if token is acquired
    //var tokennn = await GetAppTokenAsync(graphResourceId, tenantID, ClientId, userId);
    var servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
    var serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenant);
    var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetAppTokenAsync(graphResourceId, tenantID, ClientId, userId));
    AsymmetricKeyParameter myCAprivateKey = null;
    //generate a root CA cert and obtain the privateKey
    X509Certificate2 MyRootCAcert = CreateCertificateAuthorityCertificate("CN=OutlookIntegration", out myCAprivateKey);
    //add CA cert to store
    addCertToStore(MyRootCAcert, StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(MyRootCAcert.GetExpirationDateString()).ToUniversalTime();
    var startDate = DateTime.Parse(MyRootCAcert.GetEffectiveDateString()).ToUniversalTime();
    var binCert = MyRootCAcert.GetRawCertData();
    var keyCredential = new KeyCredential
        {
           CustomKeyIdentifier = MyRootCAcert.GetCertHash(),
           EndDate = expirationDate,
           KeyId = Guid.NewGuid(),
           StartDate = startDate,
           Type = "AsymmetricX509Cert",
           Usage = "Verify",
           Value = binCert
         };
     //gets stuck here when using clientsecret grant type
     var application = activeDirectoryClient.Applications["ApplicationObjectId"].ExecuteAsync().Result;
                application.KeyCredentials.Add(keyCredential);
                application.UpdateAsync().Wait();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
   Console.WriteLine(exception);
   throw;
}
```

I am now completly stuck, Anyone have any idea why it doesn't work with **Application Permissions** or why it gets stuck at `var application = activeDirectoryClient.Applications["ApplicationObjectId"].ExecuteAsync().Result;`

**Edit 1**
is it because I have my app as a web app/API that uses username and password to authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test if we want to change the **keyCredential**, `DELEGATED PERMISSIONS` is required.

If we want to update Azure AD application other properties, we could use Application Permissions.

**Reference:**

[Azure Active Directory developer glossary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-glossary#permissions)

- > "Delegated" permissions, which specify scope-based access using delegated authorization from the signed-in resource owner, are presented to the resource at run-time as "scp" claims in the client's access token.
- > "Application" permissions, which specify role-based access using the client application's credentials/identity, are presented to the resource at run-time as "roles" claims in the client's access token.

Comment: ah, but I'm the global admin of my own domain so I should at least be appble to fetch the applications by objectID or applicationID, However both return `{
 "error": {
   "code": "BadRequest",
   "message": "Invalid version",
   "innerError": {
     "request-id": "1ab1aaba-*",
     "date": "2018-07-10T09:55:23"
   }
 }
}`

Comment: I have the same package.config as yours with the same versions